# Learning - For and If statements

Tags: objective-c

I am creating several arrays from information in three files.  I want to use a key object from each file and combine some elements of each file into arrays where each index position in each array contains data associated with the key item.

I am trying to run through each file, look for a matching key value then create array objects at an index location so all related information lines-up.  I have tried several methods, NSLogged output to see if there is related data, but my program stops at the "if" statement and the data is not located in the array index desired.  If I can solve the "pvSer" object, I believe the rest will follow naturally.

```
for (t =0; t < [myInv count]; t++){
    compScott = [vScott objectAtIndex:t];
    //NSLog(@"comparison Scott Number = %@", compScott);

    //NSLog(@" ListPrice count = %lu", [listPrice count]);
    for (p = 0; p < [listPrice count]; p++){

            NSLog(@"comp Scott Number = %@", compScott);
            NSLog(@"   Loop iterations t and p = %d and %d", t,p);
            NSLog(@"pvScott Number at Index p: %@ at index %i", [pvScott  objectAtIndex:p],p);
            NSLog(@"===============================================================");
            NSLog(@" pvSer value = %@  at Index p %d", [pvSer objectAtIndex:p], p);
            NSLog(@" pvNew value = %@  at Index p %d", [pvNew objectAtIndex:p], p);
            NSLog(@" pvUsed value = %@  at Index p %d", [pvUsed objectAtIndex:p], p);
            NSLog(@" pvPlate value = %@  at Index p %d", [pvPlate objectAtIndex:p], p);
            NSLog(@" pvSht value = %@  at Index p %d", [pvSht objectAtIndex:p], p);

        NSLog(@" vScott at Index T: %@, %d and pvScott at Index P: %@, %d", [vScott objectAtIndex:t],t,[pvScott objectAtIndex:p],p);

        NSLog(@"====================================================================");

        if ([vScott objectAtIndex:t] == [pvScott objectAtIndex:p]){
                //compVSer = [pvSer objectAtIndex:p];
            [vSerPrice insertObject:[pvSer objectAtIndex:p] atIndex:t];
                NSLog(@" the value of pvSer is %@ at Index (p) %d", [pvSer objectAtIndex:p],p);
                NSLog(@" the value vSerPrice is: %@ at Index (t) %d", [vSerPrice objectAtIndex:t],t);

        NSLog(@"====================================================================");

        }
    }
```

A portion of my output related to the criteria is as follows:

```
2014-09-15 20:43:19.140 Stamp Collection[5616:303] comp Scott Number = 4435
2014-09-15 20:43:19.140 Stamp Collection[5616:303]    Loop iterations t and p = 0 and 4
2014-09-15 20:43:19.140 Stamp Collection[5616:303] pvScott Number at Index p: 4435 at index 4
2014-09-15 20:43:19.141 Stamp Collection[5616:303] ====================================================================
2014-09-15 20:43:19.141 Stamp Collection[5616:303]  pvSer value = 0.00  at Index p 4
2014-09-15 20:43:19.141 Stamp Collection[5616:303]  pvNew value = 0.95  at Index p 4
2014-09-15 20:43:19.141 Stamp Collection[5616:303]  pvUsed value = 0.25  at Index p 4
2014-09-15 20:43:19.141 Stamp Collection[5616:303]  pvPlate value = 0.00  at Index p 4
2014-09-15 20:43:19.141 Stamp Collection[5616:303]  pvSht value = 12.00  at Index p 4
2014-09-15 20:43:19.141 Stamp Collection[5616:303]  vScott at Index T: 4435, 0 and pvScott at Index P: 4435, 4
2014-09-15 20:43:19.141 Stamp Collection[5616:303] ====================================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention an error so I'll assume your if statement is always returning false.  I believe this is because the array is returning a string so `==` is comparing pointers instead of values and they will never be the same in your case.  Try `isEqualToString` instead:

```
if ([[vScott objectAtIndex:t] isEqualToString: [pvScott objectAtIndex:p]]){
```